# Mathematica: Cannot embed a correct font in my exported figures with eps format

Tags: plot, export, latex, wolfram-mathematica, eps

I made my graph in Mathematica and then I exported them as eps to my folder. Then I use Latex to use them in my document. Until today it was working perfectly but I have no clue how, my Mathematica cannot export the figure properly (I am using Ubuntu).

[The correct format of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iTni.jpg)

[Incorrect format of the plot. This is the one that I am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGnGa.jpg)

If someone has any idea please let me know.

Mathematica code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
p = {1000, 1200, 600, 1200};
u = {0.001, 0.5, 5*10^(-5), 0.05};
pu = p/u;
logy1[x_] = Log10[pu[[1]]] + x;
logy2[x_] = Log10[pu[[2]]] + x;
logy3[x_] = Log10[pu[[3]]] + x;
logy4[x_] = Log10[pu[[4]]] + x;
g1 = Plot[{logy1[x], logy2[x], logy3[x], logy4[x]}, {x, 
    Log10[5*10^(-5)], Log10[0.01]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.007]}, {Black, Thickness[0.007], 
      Dashing[{0, 0.02}]}, {Black, Thickness[0.007], 
      Dashing[{0, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02}]}, {Black, Thickness[0.007], 
      Dashing[0.02]}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Text[
      Style["Log(q/H)", Bold, 18]], 
     Text[Style["Log(Re)", Bold, 18]]}, ImageSize -> 700, 
   PlotLegends -> {Text[Style["Water", Bold, 18]], 
     Text[Style["X-Linked Gel", Bold, 18]], 
     Text[Style["CO2 (Supercritical)",
        Bold, 18]], Text[Style["Linear Gel", Bold, 18]]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {Log10[5*10^(-5)], -2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{Log10[5*10^(-5)], -2}, {-2, 8}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 18}];
Export["Figure.eps", g1]
```

Latex code:

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[height=60mm]{./figure/Figure.eps}
     \caption{My figure.}
    \label{Figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please post the relevant sections of your Mathematica and Latex code?

Comment: Did you do an update, say of anything related to mathematica or fonts or postscript or latex on your system ? If you have enabled unattented upgrades on Ubuntu, can you have a look on the update log ? Do you have access to the computer of a colleague where you could test your different code (either generation in Mathematica or integration in LaTeX) ?

Comment: @ogerard, I tried my code on other computer and it is working good with that computer. I know that there is something wrong on my machine. And the only explanation for me is that I may have done an upgrade on Ubuntu that cause this change. The eps file is bad and it does not have anything to do with LATEX. I tried my old plot and it worked perfectly with LATEX. I guess there is something to do with linux. I checked and there was no updates related to Mathematica or Latex.

Comment: take the eps from one machine to the other  and vice versa to sort out if its a mathematica problem or a issue with the rendering.  I hate to say but the best approach may be to use a raster format...

Comment: I could not find the reason so I reinstalled Mathematica and it resolve itself. Before this I also restored it but it did not help.